# ws .close() custom code isn't being passed to on(close) event

Tags: javascript, node.js, ws

I'm using `ws` library in nodejs.

I have (server side):

```
wsServer.on("connect", (socket) => {
  socket.on("close", (code, reason) => {
    console.log(code, reason)
  }
}
```

I sometimes then close a socket (also in on the server side!) when some conditions are met by calling `socket.close(3000, "my custom reason")`.

The socket is then successfully closed but the console logs `"1006, ''"`.

I don't understand why my custom code and reason aren't getting passed into the close event.

How can I do it?

Comment: In the browser, [the `close` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/close_event) contains the `code` sent by the *server*. I suspect that [in the nodejs library](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/doc/ws.md#event-close-1) it's no different - you don't get the `code` that you used yourself (which presumably you already know) but the code that the remote sent

Comment: @Bergi I'm executing socket.close() on the nodejs server, when some conditions are met (I'm not doing it client side). I want to be able to log such conditions. Is this impossible?

Comment: Just log them when you are calling `.close()` then. The `close` event is for when the client closes the connection. While the spec calls for "*When sending a Close frame in response, the endpoint typically echos the status code it received*", it sounds like in your case it simply closes the TCP connection, leading to the 1006 client close status.